# Finding the dimensions of the rectangular swimming pool

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, word-problem

> A rectangular swimming pool is $6$ ft. deep.  One side of the pool is $2.5$ times longer than the other side.  The amount of water needed to fill the pool is $2160$ cubic feet.  Find the dimensions.

Do you set it up like the following?$$2.5x^2 = 2160$$

The answer I got is:
\begin{align*}
2.5x & = 73.5\\
x & = 29.4
\end{align*}

Is that correct?

Comment: You forgot about the $6$.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  That's part of the dimensions, so how do I include it in the answer?

Comment: The volume of a box of width $w$, length $l$, and height $h$ is $w\times l\times h$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be the shorter side of the pool (the width). Then the longer side of the pool is $2.5x$. Thus the volume of water in the pool is $(6)(x)(2.5x)$. Set this equal to $2160$ and solve for $x$.

Our equation simplifies to $15x^2=2160$, and then nicely to $x^2=144$.

Thus the pool has width $12$ feet and length $30$ feet.

Comment: Is there egg on my face?!  Thank you very much!